# Can I log graphic data from video game before it goes to gpu?

Tags: c++, c, graphics, gpu

I am trying to understand how graphics are processed. Is it possible for a program to get graphic data before it is sent to the gpu, log it, send it to the gpu, get the processed results back from the gpu and send it to the video game requesting the process? I am not sure if I explained any of this clearly, but I am relatively new to this top, so I am sorry for that.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about what you're planning to do? Generally speaking, it's easier to offer advice when we see what the overall objective is rather than the specific strategy you're trying to employ. (It's to avoid the ["XY Problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem))

Comment: Basically what I am asking is, can someone build a software that sits in between the graphic processing requestor and the gpu. An overall graphic processing architecture flow similar to:

Video Game => Software that collects data => GPU

then when the gpu processes the data to send back:

GPU => Software that collects data => Video Game

Comment: That would be the driver of your graphics card. What kind of data do you expect gpu to send back? The host processor might be able in general to access the framebuffer if it really wants to and there is no some kind of DRM on the way. But it won't be able to keep up with it as in general modern GPUs have a data bandwidth *much* higher than CPUs.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @EugeneSh. So maybe I should reformat my question?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Change the format of the graphic data processed before it is displayed on the screen.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The host process can't get access to the frame buffer allocated by a separate process. Doing this would require a driver shim or some sort of API intercept library that could, perhaps, copy the render target back to the host after a present.

Comment: @3Dave As far as I know, hardware-wise the DRAM where FB is accessible from CPU. Of course there might be restrictions in the GPU firmware/VBIOS/Driver fencing this off.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You can map it and read / write, but there are a number of driver- and api-dependent restrictions (duh) and you'd have to know where it is. I'm not sure how you'd pull that off with an existing game, esp. considering that OP's goal is to add a post-processing step. It's an interesting question, but ultimately impractical unless I'm missing something. (Wouldn't be the first or last time that happened.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by "graphic data" in this case, so I'll assume you're referring to the final rendered frame.

In that case, the answer is "no."

The frame buffer is generated (rendered) on the GPU. The only thing on the CPU, in any modern game, is a list of drawing commands that are sent to the video driver and translated into other commands that the GPU understands. There is no image on the CPU side unless you render to a texture and copy it back to the host.

Regarding the second part of your question:

The "game requesting the process" doesn't really get much in the way of feedback from the GPU. The display - monitor, HMD, or whatever - shows the contents of a buffer that resides on the GPU. The game never receives the rendered frame, unless it really wants it and goes through a lot of trouble to copy it back to the host. Rendering is very much an open-loop process. Aside from some error & status codes, the host application really can't verify what's happening on the GPU (again, without rendering to an off-screen buffer and copying that data back to the CPU).

I'd search for "OpenGL render pipeline" to get a better idea of how this works. (DirectX works the same way, btw.)

Now, if what you're looking for is a better understanding of how the rendering API calls in the game contribute to the final output on the screen, you could look at some tools like RenderDoc, which will let you see the effect on a frame buffer (and other render targets) of each API call. It's not trivial to parse what you'll see in these tools unless you have some familiarity with the API in use.

Comment: So, the GPU never sends any information back to the requestor? The requestor sends it to the GPU and the GPU handles the displaying of data to the displaying device? Again sorry for my terminology and explanation of my thoughts, I am a novice to this.

Comment: Is DirectX still a thing?

Comment: @UsernameGoesHere1 That is correct. It may be helpful to think of the GPU as an entirely separate computer (and it really is), that listens over a network (PCIe) for things that it needs to do. The video driver does provide *some* feedback in the form of error codes, etc., but,l for the most part, you just have to do a lot of testing before shipping to know what's happening on the display.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't know. Are Windows and XBox still a thing?

Comment: @3Dave Well, I am just judging from the fact I was't required to install newest directx software every other day as I used to before... MAybe it's because I am not gaming anymore

Comment: @EugeneSh. Every AAA Windows title uses DirectX. The perf difference between it and GL on Windows is substantial. Vulkan is seeing very slow adoption on Windows (still by far the most popular gaming platform other than mobile) and DX12 is a mess. So, DX11 - which is *very* stable at this point, and well it should be - is still where the money is.

Comment: @3Dave So is it possible for me to grab that data, and change it? Like applying some kind of blur to the data before it is displayed? Also, is it possible for me to use a really low-levered programming language, and take some time to do my homework and gain relevant access between the gpu and display that way? Is such access even permitted by any GPU manufacturers?

Comment: @UsernameGoesHere1 Technically possible? It's software. Everything is possible. Practical? Not really. You could present a virtual rendering device - like the WARP device in DX - and somehow tap into that. But, without modifying the driver, you're not going to easily be able to insert your own commands in the pipe. And, something like a blur, would involve rendering the entire scene to a texture that you don't have, running a post-process shader which you don't have, and then writing the result back to the frame buffer that you don't have access to.

Comment: Okay, I understand now, thank you so much for all of this information, I really appreciate it now! Is there anything I should do on here, other than accepting this as answer, to help other's this may benefit?

Comment: @UsernameGoesHere1 Nope, you're good. Thanks for accepting. It's a good question - I'm glad you asked.

Comment: You are very welcome, and thank you, I am glad I asked, I was able to gain a lot of insight, as well as many resources to research, on how graphics are processed.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The components that used to be the parts of DirectX (or what is left of them) are core Windows system components by now. They are integral part of Windows; they ship as part of Windows. There is no DirectX SDK anymore and nothing that would have to be installed. Consider the fact that, basically since Windows Vista, the Windows desktop itself is being rendered using Direct3D…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel There is a DX SDK, it's just installed as part of the Windows SDK rather than being kept separate.